# How to create Makefile for multiple files in multiple directories?

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, g++

Good morning,
I new in c++ and I am trying to compile my simple code to executable form. I will explain structure of project.

```
- main.cpp
- /utility/server.h
- /utility/server.cpp
```

I enclose file sources for complete information.
`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "utility/server.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace server;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
    std::cout << "Your server name is: " << server::get_domain() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

`server.cpp`

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "server.h"

namespace server {
    static char* get_domain() {
        return getenv("SERVER_NAME");
    }
}
```

To my Makefile I added comments to understand what I want to do.

```
#
# 'make'        build executable file 
# 'make clean'  removes all .o and executable files
#

# define the C compiler to use
CC = g++

# define any compile-time flags
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

# define any directories containing header files other than /usr/include
INCLUDES = -I../utility

# define the C++ source files
SRCS = main.cpp utility/server.cpp

# define the C++ object files 
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

# define the executable file 
MAIN = executable.cgi

#
# The following part of the makefile is generic
#

.PHONY: depend clean

all:    $(MAIN)

$(MAIN): $(OBJS) 
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS)

# this is a suffix replacement rule for building .o's from .cpp's
.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -cpp $<  -o $@

clean:
        $(RM) *.o *~ $(MAIN)

depend: $(SRCS)
        makedepend $(INCLUDES) $^
```

And finally error from compilation

```
g++ -Wall -g -I../utility -o executable.cgi main.o utility/server.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "server::get_domain()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [executable.cgi] Error 1
```

From error message I understood there is problem with `utility` folder, but I don't know how to fix it.
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: And BTW, do see [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1362568)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `server.cpp`, here:

```
namespace server {
    static char* get_domain() {
        return getenv("SERVER_NAME");
    }
}
```

You have made `char* server::get_domain()` a [`static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static) function, making
its definition visible only within this translation unit and invisible to
the linker. Remove the keyword `static` here, and also in `server.h` if you have declared the function `static` there.

A `namespace` is not a `class` or `struct`. Confusingly,

```
namespace server {
    static char* get_domain() {
        return getenv("SERVER_NAME");
    }
}
```

`server::get_domain()` is a *static* function in that namespace. But

```
struct server {
    static char* get_domain() {
        return getenv("SERVER_NAME");
    }
};
```

it is a *global* function in that class, which the linker can see.